# How to show merged differences between two files?

Tags: bash, diff

How can I get only diff letters between two files?

For example,

file1:

> ```
> aaa;bbb;ccc
> 123;456;789
> a1a;b1b;c1c
> ```

file2:

> ```
> aAa;bbb;ccc
> 123;406;789
> a1a;b1b;c5c
> ```

After diff I should get only this string of difference from the second file: `A05`

Answer (score 2):

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(fold -w 1 file1) <(fold -w 1 file2) |
sed 's/.*\(.\)$/\1/' | paste -s -d '' -
```

This uses process substitution with `fold` to turn each file into a column of characters that's one character wide and then compares them with `diff`.

The `-y` option prints lines next to each other, and `--suppress-common-lines` skips lines that are the same between both files. Until here, the output looks like this:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(fold -w 1 file1) <(fold -w 1 file2)
a                                 | A
5                                 | 0
1                                 | 5
```

We're only interested in the the last character of each line. We use sed to discard the rest:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(fold -w 1 file1) <(fold -w 1 file2) |
> sed 's/.*\(.\)$/\1/'
A
0
5
```

To get these into a single line, we pipe to `paste` with the `-s` option (serial) and the empty string as the delimiter (`-d ''`). The dash tells `paste` to read from standard in.

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(fold -w 1 file1) <(fold -w 1 file2) |
> sed 's/.*\(.\)$/\1/' | paste -s -d '' -
A05
```

---

An alternative, if you have the GNU diffutils at your disposal, is `cmp`:

```
$ cmp -lb file1 file2 | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d '\n'
A05
```

`cmp` compares files byte by byte. The `-l` option ("verbose") makes it print all the differences, not just the first one; the `-b` options make it add the ASCII interpretation of the differing bytes:

```
$ cmp -lb file1 file2
 2 141 a    101 A
18  65 5     60 0
34  61 1     65 5
```

The awk command reduces this output to the fifth column, and `tr` removes the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

For the example given,
you could compare the files character by character and if there is a difference, print the character of the second file. Here's one way to do that:

```
paste <(fold -w1 file1) <(fold -w1 file2) | \
while read c1 c2; do [[ $c1 = $c2 ]] || printf $c2; done
```

For the given example, this will print `A05`.